# Are there common causes of a text message sound in the night, but no text message?

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone 3GS has made the text message sound twice at like 3:30 am but when I look at it there is no text.

This is hard to explain to my husband, it's making us both paranoid! Can I look somewhere to figure out what's happening?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't gotten any mail or something like that can cause the same tone to be played?

Comment: Do you use iCloud? And if so, is your storage nearly full?

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you have another app that may be giving you untimely notifications. You can check by opening Settings.app > Notifications. Scroll through that list and tap on each application that you don't want sound notifications on. Scroll down slightly and turn Sounds off.

Unfortunately, there appears to be no (easy) way to look up notifications logs. I say easy, because notifications logs should be accessible with a jailbreak, however, as of writing, there is no jailbreak available for iOS 6 - if you have that installed.

As a last resort, if you are on iOS 6, you can also schedule Do-Not-Disturb times, from when you go to bed to when you get up. One thing you could do to verify that it is indeed the text tone, is change the text tone to something different. If the different sound goes off at night again (or anytime without a text message actually appearing to come in), that would narrow it down to it indeed being a pseudo-text-notification. At that point, Do-Not-Disturb, would seem like a reasonable "hack".

Comment: I never get mail alerts and I couldn't find anything in my apps that would have been on as far as a notification except messages.

Comment: Doesn't the message to update iOS to a new version make the same sound? That's not a notification that can be turned off, that I know.

Comment: @Lizzan, that is a possible option, however, I wouldn't have expected it to go off twice (if that's two times in a row like texts default sound). Honestly, though, I've never had that alert - I've always been quick to update.

Comment: @Nancy, I just assumed that it went off one particular night two consecutive times. In the same way a text notification sounds - two notifications two minutes apart. Is this correct or was it two *different* nights? Just to double check what Alex said, check out Settings.app > Sounds. See if any of the other Sounds have the same tone as your Messages (texts).

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a notification from an app (not a text) and only happens if you've turned off the ability for an app to show you alerts (either banner or popup) but NOT disabled sounds at the same time (in my opinion, Apple should not permit this as it makes no sense to have your phone set up like this).

To fix this: 
In your notification preferences, check all the apps and see if any are in this state. If they are, enable the alert popup (or disable sounds) and this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

IOS 7 -> Turn the repetitive text message notification :

Settings -> Notification Center -> In include Messages -> Scroll down to find the Repeat alert option and switch it to "Never"

Comment: Does the 3GS support iOS7?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.  is the text message preceded by a 'half moon'?
you may have 'Do Not Disturb" on.  I didn't but when I pressed "Details" for that caller, (upper right hand corner of the text screen)  I found that I had the 'Do Not Disturb' button turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a hidden folder excepting messages ( with a password) so no one can read messages! Except of course the person who has the password. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps there is a notification for when the battery is fully charged?
I have that on my non-iPhone, and it typically goes off in the middle of the night if I forget to set it to silent-mode.

Comment: There is no such notification that charging is complete on iOS unless you jailbreak it or download an app that somehow manages to get a notification for that event.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It was not two consecutive nights, a week apart or so actually. Still not sure what it was but I'm going to do the "do not disturb" when I can remember. I did have an unread text message from earlier but I have my phone set not to get second alerts on those.

Comment: iPhones don't have a battery charged notification.